# What is the name for those lines used in place of words?

Tags: terminology

What is the name for those lines used in place of words, for example in a cartoon contract? Sometimes they're straight and sometimes they're wavy.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Dummy" Or "Greek"

or a combination of the two.. Dummy greek, dummy greeking, dummy text, greeked text.. etc.

[Lorem Ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/) is often used to dummy text rather than using a series of lines. Lines look like, well, lines. Using Lorem Ipsum (or similar) helps the text still *look* like text, even though most can't read the Latin text (since Latin is a dead language).

Comment: ah -- thanks! Greeking was the terminology I was using. (hard to search when you don't know what it's called!)

Comment: Yeah, you have to include either "dummy" or "text" when searching. Otherwise you just get a lot of stuff related to Greece. `:)`

Comment: re. "most can't read the text": while Lorem Ipsum is loosely based on some Cicero text, it has no real meaning; interestingly this connection was made only very recently - a few months ago at the time of writing; previously the Lorem Ipsum was just thought to be some random words put together. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#cite_note-Microsoft-7)

Comment: @VladimirCravero according to the linked WP article, the link was discovered around 1982, and published in 1994, significantly more than "a few months ago" ;) "The discovery of the text's origin is attributed to Richard McClintock, a Latin scholar at Hampden–Sydney College. McClintock connected Lorem ipsum to Cicero's writing sometime before 1982 [...]. McClintock first published his discovery in a 1994 letter"

Comment: What do the Greek call it? Αγγλικά?

Comment: Dummy English maybe? So, Ψευδά αγγλικά

Comment: thanks @Zhaph-BenDuguid for correcting me; I think I mixed up the sources dates and the actual dates :D

Comment: I went through a whole bunch of searching on Google for about 15 minutes with various combinations "dummy" / "lines" / "fake" / "text" / "graphics" / "in place of" / "cartoon" etc. with no luck other than pulling up lots results of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: What is it you are looking for specifically? Lorem Ipsum is relatively standard for such usage. The lines are non-standard and traditionally only seen in small icons.

Comment: @Scott: Lines or boxes would also historically have been used by some page-layout software in contexts involving limited memory or CPU time.  Especially in the days before sophisticated kerning, determination of text flow would require merely loading a font width table, versus having to load or generate all the letterforms.

Comment: Possibly... I started with computers at the birth of their use for design/layout - i.e. Illustrator 1, Photoshop 2, etc.... they have always been capable of using text to dummy greek anything. You *must* be referring to circa 1970s or earlier. But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: But yes. When mechanicals were created by hand, lines were created with a ruling pen for dummy greeking.. the lines were merely broken up to simulate text.